# How to setup an sqlite datasource for JPA on Websphere Liberty?

Tags: java, sqlite, jpa, websphere-liberty

I'm trying to use sqlite as persistence layer in my application and interact with it via JPA. But whenever I connect either for reading or for writing I get java.sql.SQLException.

I use Websphere Liberty webProfile8 19.0.0.1 with EclipseLink 2.6.8 as JPA provider.

There is a load script which puts some initial data to TEST_ENTITY table and it works with no issues. Probably the way how JPA manages db connections for entities is different.

If I switch to Apache Derby datasource everything works just fine.

Did anybody face something similar?

server.xml:

```
<library id="sqlitelib">
    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/libs" id="sqlite-jdbc" includes="sqlite-jdbc-3.23.1.jar"/>
</library>

<dataSource id="annodb" 
   type="javax.sql.DataSource"
   isolationLevel="TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE"
   jndiName="jdbc/annodb">
    <jdbcDriver          
        javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource="org.sqlite.javax.SQLiteConnectionPoolDataSource" 
        javax.sql.DataSource="org.sqlite.SQLiteDataSource" 
        libraryRef="sqlitelib"/>
    <properties URL="jdbc:sqlite:c:/__anno.db"/>
</dataSource>
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="annodb">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/annodb</jta-data-source>
        <!-- non-jta-data-source>jdbc/annodb</non-jta-data-source-->            
        <class>com.ibm.zurich.ainews.domain.anno.entities.TestEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <!--property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="both"/-->
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="ServerLogger"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="createSchemaDDL.sql"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="dropSchemaDDL.sql"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target" value="create.ddl"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="load.sql"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.native-sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.drop-target" value="drop.ddl"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

full stack trace:

```
[2/21/19 23:33:32:462 CET] 000000e0 connection    3   client acquired: 642755657
[2/21/19 23:33:32:465 CET] 000000e0 transaction   3   TX binding to tx mgr, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
[2/21/19 23:33:32:465 CET] 000000e0 transaction   3   acquire unit of work: -1982630449
[2/21/19 23:33:32:465 CET] 000000e0 transaction   3   begin unit of work flush
[2/21/19 23:33:32:465 CET] 000000e0 transaction   3   end unit of work flush
[2/21/19 23:33:32:465 CET] 000000e0 query         3   Execute query ReadAllQuery(name="TestEntity.findAll" referenceClass=TestEntity sql="SELECT PKEY, FIELD FROM TEST_ENTITY")
[2/21/19 23:33:32:466 CET] 000000e0 connection    3   Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
[2/21/19 23:33:32:466 CET] 000000e0 connection    3   reconnecting to external connection pool
[2/21/19 23:33:32:467 CET] 000000e0 sql           3   SELECT PKEY, FIELD FROM TEST_ENTITY
[2/21/19 23:33:32:477 CET] 000000e0 connection    3   Connection released to connection pool [read].
[2/21/19 23:33:32:477 CET] 000000e0 eclipselink   W   CWWJP9991W: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.8.WAS-v20181218-0accd7f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: statement is not executing
Error Code: 0
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="TestEntity.findAll" referenceClass=TestEntity sql="SELECT PKEY, FIELD FROM TEST_ENTITY")
[2/21/19 23:33:32:478 CET] 000000e0 BusinessExcep E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "testRead" on bean "BeanId(ear#war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#AnnoMgr, null)". Exception data: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.8.WAS-v20181218-0accd7f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: statement is not executing
Error Code: 0
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="TestEntity.findAll" referenceClass=TestEntity sql="SELECT PKEY, FIELD FROM TEST_ENTITY")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:473)
    at com.ibm.zurich.ainews.domain.anno.mgr.AnnoMgr.testRead(AnnoMgr.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1196.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invokeProceed(EJSContainer.java:4886)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:592)
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.ejb.impl.InterceptorChain.proceed(InterceptorChain.java:119)
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.ejb.impl.EJBCDIInterceptorWrapper.invokeInterceptors(EJBCDIInterceptorWrapper.java:131)
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.ejb.impl.EJBCDIInterceptorWrapper.aroundInvoke(EJBCDIInterceptorWrapper.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1195.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InterceptorProxy.invokeInterceptor(InterceptorProxy.java:189)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:577)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.ejb.interceptor.WeldSessionBeanInterceptorWrapper.aroundInvoke(WeldSessionBeanInterceptorWrapper.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1194.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InterceptorProxy.invokeInterceptor(InterceptorProxy.java:189)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:577)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.doAroundInterceptor(InvocationContextImpl.java:298)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.doAroundInvoke(InvocationContextImpl.java:267)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invoke(EJSContainer.java:4788)
    at com.ibm.zurich.ainews.domain.anno.mgr.EJSLocalNSLAnnoMgr_99272aa0.testRead(EJSLocalNSLAnnoMgr_99272aa0.java)
    at com.ibm.zurich.ainews.api.stories.svc.TestSvc.testAnnoDB(TestSvc.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1184.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invokeProceed(EJSContainer.java:4886)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:592)
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.ejb.impl.InterceptorChain.proceed(InterceptorChain.java:119)
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.ejb.impl.EJBCDIInterceptorWrapper.invokeInterceptors(EJBCDIInterceptorWrapper.java:131)
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.ejb.impl.EJBCDIInterceptorWrapper.aroundInvoke(EJBCDIInterceptorWrapper.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1195.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InterceptorProxy.invokeInterceptor(InterceptorProxy.java:189)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:577)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.ejb.interceptor.WeldSessionBeanInterceptorWrapper.aroundInvoke(WeldSessionBeanInterceptorWrapper.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1194.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InterceptorProxy.invokeInterceptor(InterceptorProxy.java:189)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:577)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.doAroundInterceptor(InvocationContextImpl.java:298)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.doAroundInvoke(InvocationContextImpl.java:267)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invoke(EJSContainer.java:4788)
    at com.ibm.zurich.ainews.api.stories.svc.EJSLocalNSLTestSvc_32d4537b.testAnnoDB(EJSLocalNSLTestSvc_32d4537b.java)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1184.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.ejb.JaxRsFactoryBeanEJBCustomizer.serviceInvoke(JaxRsFactoryBeanEJBCustomizer.java:333)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.performInvocation(LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.java:637)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsInvoker.performInvocation(LibertyJaxRsInvoker.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsInvoker.invoke(LibertyJaxRsInvoker.java:273)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsInvoker.invoke(LibertyJaxRsInvoker.java:444)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:309)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:124)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:271)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.endpoint.AbstractJaxRsWebEndpoint.invoke(AbstractJaxRsWebEndpoint.java:134)
    at com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet.handleRequest(IBMRestServlet.java:146)
    at com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet.doGet(IBMRestServlet.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet.service(IBMRestServlet.java:96)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1255)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:743)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:440)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1221)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1005)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:75)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:923)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:279)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:1047)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:417)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:376)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:466)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:331)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:70)
    at com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1803)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:501)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:571)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:926)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1015)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:239)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.8.WAS-v20181218-0accd7f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: statement is not executing
Error Code: 0
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="TestEntity.findAll" referenceClass=TestEntity sql="SELECT PKEY, FIELD FROM TEST_ENTITY")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:713)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2061)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:715)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2767)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2720)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1175)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:911)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1134)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1863)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1845)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1810)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: statement is not executing
    at org.sqlite.core.CoreStatement.checkOpen(CoreStatement.java:50)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.clearParameters(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:37)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.closeWrapper(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject.close(WSJdbcObject.java:152)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject.close(WSJdbcObject.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.closeStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.releaseStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1674)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:705)
    ... 109 more
```

Comment: at a first glance it looks like you have configured everything properly. Can you please update your question with the full stack trace? It should be available under messages.log. What you currently have shown has internal classes redacted so it's hard to tell what the code path is.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for responding!

I have attached full stack trace. From my side it doesn't look more meaningful though :) It seems that the connection somehow gets lost. CoreStatement.checkOpen just checks if a pointer is not null.  Not sure if has anything to do with connections pool.